# How to find this regex using PHP

Tags: php, regex

find all the `<1></1> and <2></2> and <3></3>...`  in a string.

Comment: Before you go too far down this road, please read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<(\d+)></\1>
```

should work. This ensures that the regex won't match `<1></4>` for example.

`\1` is here a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) which must match exactly the same string as the first capturing group (the `(\d+)` in the first angle brackets).

Comment: Should I? I don't know. But I did. By the way, http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great site to learn.

Answer (score 1):

One regex to match any of them?

```
<([1-3])></\1>
```

Should there code allow for anything to be posted in between the `>` and the `<`? Something like this then:

```
<([1-3])>(.*?)</\1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex: `<[0-9]></[0-9]>`

**EDIT:** To avoid that the search matches `<2></3>` too, you can use a sub-expression and a  backreference to instantiate it: `<([0-9])></\1>`

Comment: this would match <1></2> as well, tho

Comment: but this will also find `<2></3> ... `

Answer (score 0):

```
<STYLE[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/STYLE[^>]*>

Just replace STYLE with your tag like 1, 2 whatever.
```